# RACObserve for value update in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm having a problem reacting to a value change in NSMutableArray.

I have the following (somewhat simplified) code to detect a change:

```
[[RACObserve(self, postedImagesIds) filter:^BOOL(NSMutableArray * postedImagesIds) {
    return [postedImagesIds count] > 0;
}] subscribeNext:^(NSMutableArray * postedImagesIds) {
    [self uploadFields:fields];
}];
```

The idea here is to call `uploadFields` when there is a change in `NSMutableArray postedImagesIds`. But not only when a new element is added, but also when a value is updated like so:

```
[self.postedImagesIds replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:imagePosted.imagePostedId];
```

Then thing is that when the value is updated, `RACObserve` never knows!! Is there a way to recognize this change ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done, sort of. The important part is that you must perform your NSMutableArray mutation via KVC on `self`, rather than on an independent reference to the NSMutableArray object. In other words, it won't work if you do this:

```
[self.postedImagesIds addObject:imagePosted.imagePostedId];
or
[self.postedImagesIds replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:imagePosted.imagePostedId];
```

instead, you must add or replace the object like this:

```
NSMutableArray *fromKVC = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"postedImagesIds"];
[fromKVC addObject:imagePosted.imagePostedId];
or
[fromKVC replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:imagePosted.imagePostedId];
```

This is because the KVO established by `RACObserve()` is relative to the object you pass in as its first parameter (`self`, in this case), so only KVC-compliant mutations that pass through the observed object will trigger the observation notifications.

Comment: Cool, I had read about this but didn't understand the reason. Now it's much more clear. I managed to get it working by observing a counter but this is much better. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, of course! Sorry I didn't do it before. Just wanted to test it first :D